# Jquery function not being registered

Tags: jquery

Im trying to generate a html table using Jquery

```
slicedata.forEach(function(e, i, a) {
    var obj = e;
    $('#ticket-table').append('<tr><td>' + obj.created_dt + '</td><td>' + obj.ticket_num + '</td> <td>' + obj.division + '</td><td>' + obj.pg + '</td> <td>' + obj.duration + '</td><td>' + obj.error_count + '</td><td>' + obj.outage_caused + '</td><td>' + obj.system_caused + '</td><td>' + obj.addt_notes + '</td><td><button id="edit' + i + '"">edit</button></td></tr>');
})
```

and then registering a event for button ids -

```
$('#edit0').click(function() {
    alert('clicked')
    //load_datatable('N')
})
```

THe html table is generating correctly using Jquery but the event is not being registered.

All this code is inside document.ready() function

Comment: When does the second code block run in relation to the first - before or after?

Comment: It runs after the first.

Comment: are you looking for the `.each()` function?  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: @James:I was able to fix it.. The second code was in a separate function but was not registered after the element was corrected..When I moved the code inside it works now...

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind your event to a parent element instead of the dynamically generated element.

```
$("body").on("click", "#edit0", function() {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

Or in your specific case you could do:

```
$("#ticket-table").on("click", "#edit0", function() {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

Always bind your event to a parent element that you know is always there when your actual element is dynamically added so that you won't have to worry about binding the event again.

Answer (score 0):

you are appending the control dynamically so try this one.

```
$('body').delegate('input[id*="edit"]','click',function() {
    alert('clicked')
    //load_datatable('N')
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#edit0').click(function() {
        alert('clicked')
            //load_datatable('N')
    })
```

The problem with the above is that it assumes that `#edit0`is already part of the `DOM` by the time it loads this piece of code.

Try changing it to:

```
$('#edit0').on('click', function() {
        alert('clicked')
            //load_datatable('N')
    })
```

If `#edit0` doesn't yet exist but will be part of something else in the DOM, try binding the `$.on` to a parent container instead, and then pointing it to `#edit0`:

```
 $('#parent').on('click', '#edit0', function() {
            alert('clicked')
                //load_datatable('N')
        })
```

The `$.on()` event handler will attach an event listener to anything that exists in the HTML, whether it's already loaded or not. 
Documentation of `.on()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Uh, `$('#edit0').on()` also assumes that.  It needs to be pointed at something that exists in the DOM when `on()` is called.

Comment: Your answer contradicts itself a little now - you have two different ways of dealing with "if `#edit0` doesn't exist in the dom yet", only one of which will actually work.